# AND OR in Set Analysis - Qlik Sense

Tags: qliksense, set-analysis

This is a typical and/or question in set analysis where I am stuck for a long time.

[image]

I want to sum the amount for those ids, where:

1. type_of_entry is both 'Revenue and Expense' or 'Revenue and Labor'
2. revenue type is 'CAF'

Expected ids are shown in bold colors

Eg...id 1 exists for both revenue and expense. Similarly, id 2 and 3 exist for both revenue and labor.

Result - > amount = 55 (5+40+10)

I have tried the below set analysis but is not working:

[image]

I would appreciate any help on this.

Regards

Sagnik

Comment: Equation tried - 

sum({<type_of_entry = {'Expense','Labor'}>*type_of_entry = {'Revenue'}*revenue_type={'CAF'}}amount)

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: Output: 55 (5+40+10)

Comment: I'll assume you want to show 55 in text object. I'd not do that with `set analysis`. I'd put flags in a load script so your aggregation becomes easier with analysis later.

Comment: That's one way of doing it, but I have dynamic scenarios like that, because of which editing load editor won't be helpful. I figured out the solution.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Script -

[image]

The p() function extracts the possible values based on your filter, in this case, it was Expense and Labor, and * operator does the and operation. In short, you can have all the desired ids , and then apply the revenue_type filter.

Similarly, there is an e() function that extracts the excluded values.

This answer is not mine, Mr. Sunny Talwar helped me to get the solution for this question. It worked.

Comment: Very neat, @Sagnik. Thank you for sharing! If you see a tick-mark by your answer, I encourage you to click it and mark your own answer as accepted to put closure to your question. That allows others to see that the question had a workable solution (which is your and Mr. Talwar's solution).

Answer (score 1):

Are you accept the answer which is Python solution?

## python solution

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Expense', 1, 10, '-'],
    ['Labor', 2, 20, '-'],
    ['Labor', 3, 50, '-'],
    ['Revenue', 1, 5, 'CAF'],
    ['Revenue', 2, 30, 'NORM'],
    ['Revenue', 2, 40, 'CAF'],
    ['Revenue', 3, 10, 'CAF'],
    ['Revenue', 4, 20, 'NORM'],
    ['Revenue', 5, 30, 'CAF']
], columns=['type_of_entry', 'id', 'amount', 'revenue_type'])

series_caf = df[df['revenue_type'].eq('CAF')]
filter_id_list = series_caf['id'].to_list()  # 1, 2, 3, 5
result_amount = 0
dict_ok = defaultdict(list)
for cur_id in filter_id_list:
    is_revenue = len(df[(df.id == cur_id) & (df.type_of_entry == 'Revenue')]) > 0
    is_expense = len(df[(df.id == cur_id) & (df.type_of_entry == 'Expense')]) > 0
    is_labor = len(df[(df.id == cur_id) & (df.type_of_entry == 'Labor')]) > 0
    is_ok = (is_revenue and is_expense) or (is_revenue and is_labor)
    if is_ok:
        cur_amount = series_caf[series_caf.id == cur_id].amount.values[0]
        result_amount += cur_amount
        dict_ok['id'].append(cur_id)
        dict_ok['amount'].append(cur_amount)
        dict_ok['ok_reason (REL)'].append(is_revenue*100+is_expense*10+is_labor)

df_result_info = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_ok)
print(df_result_info)
print(result_amount)
```

output

```
   id  amount  ok_reason (REL)
0   1       5              110
1   2      40              101
2   3      10              101
55
```

Comment: It tells you the ``amount`` and tells you why. for example REL = 110, it means **Revenue** and **Expense** (all of above is **CAF** so I don't show it deliberately)

Comment: Hi Carlson, I appreciate your work and explanation, and it's right. But unfortunately, you cannot run python codes inside Qlik Sense widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Thank's for your example, it's easier to understand.

I suggest you get the values of the concatenated id's first. For example:

`Concat(<type_of_entry={'Expense','Labor'}>id, ',')`

Now you can get the sum of this ids, so:

```
Sum(<id={"$(=Concat(<type_of_entry={'Expense','Labor'}>id, ','))"},revenue_type={'CAF'}> amount)
```

And this should work, I didn't verify this works with any dataset but it should!

Have a nice day!